# upload and edit image dynamically - graphically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to open an image and edit it graphically and dynamically before upload. At first the user should choose the image file and interface return me the path of file, then the user should see the preview, and if he/she wants to select all or a piece of the image for upload.

Are there any functions in javascript or jquery that can do this for me, or do I have to use plugins, and if so, which plugins?

Comment: There's a very good one called Google.

Comment: i googled it and i found nothing special

Comment: Try looking for a HTML5 canvas, and, depending on your server, make the same changes using server-side scripts before storing the image itself.

Comment: Googled for 'Javascript image cropping' ..first hit http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
There are many good jQuery plugins are available to crop image on the fly,
```

HTML Image Uploading Form

```
    <!-- image preview area-->
   <img id="uploadPreview" style="display:none;"/>

    <!-- image uploading form -->
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

    <!-- hidden inputs -->
    <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
    <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
    <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
    <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
     </form>
```

jQuery and JavaScript

```
    // set info for cropping image using hidden fields
function setInfo(i, e) {
  $('#x').val(e.x1);
  $('#y').val(e.y1);
  $('#w').val(e.width);
  $('#h').val(e.height);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var p = $("#uploadPreview");

  // prepare instant preview
  $("#uploadImage").change(function(){
    // fadeOut or hide preview
    p.fadeOut();

    // prepare HTML5 FileReader
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
     p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
    };
  });

  // implement imgAreaSelect plug in (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)
  $('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
    // set crop ratio (optional)
    aspectRatio: '1:1',
    onSelectEnd: setInfo
  });
});
```

PHP :

```
 <?php

  $valid_exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');
  $max_file_size = 200 * 1024; #200kb
  $nw = $nh = 200; # image with & height

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if ( isset($_FILES['image']) ) {
    if (! $_FILES['image']['error'] && $_FILES['image']['size'] < $max_file_size) {
      # get file extension
      $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
      # file type validity
      if (in_array($ext, $valid_exts)) {
      $path = 'uploads/' . uniqid()  . '.' . $ext;
      $size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      # grab data form post request
      $x = (int) $_POST['x'];
      $y = (int) $_POST['y'];
      $w = (int) $_POST['w'] ? $_POST['w'] : $size[0];
      $h = (int) $_POST['h'] ? $_POST['h'] : $size[1];
      # read image binary data
      $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
      # create v image form binary data
      $vImg = imagecreatefromstring($data);
      $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
      # copy image
      imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $vImg, 0, 0, $x, $y, $nw, $nh, $w, $h);
      # save image
      imagejpeg($dstImg, $path);
      # clean memory
      imagedestroy($dstImg);
      echo "<img src='$path' />";

    } else {
      echo 'unknown problem!';
    } 
    } else {
      echo 'file is too small or large';
    }
  } else {
    echo 'file not set';
  }
} else {
  echo 'bad request!';
}

  ?>
```

Referrence url: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/image-upload-and-crop-with-jquery-and.html

Comment: Mr.Downvoter may i know the reason, given url having step by step basic tutorial to understand the image upload and preview concept. what is the wrong on that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: I didn't downvote but please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.